# Dynamically change background based on active slide in React Swiper

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm building a React application using the Swiper component to display a carousel of movie cards. I want to dynamically change the background of the entire body or a specific div within the app component based on the currently active movie slide.

Here's the relevant code:

CardSlider.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/free-mode';
import 'swiper/css/autoplay';
import { FreeMode, Autoplay, Navigation } from 'swiper';

const CardSlider = ({ movies }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={7.5}
        spaceBetween={30}
        freeMode={true}
        modules={[FreeMode, Autoplay, Navigation]}
        className="mySwiper"
        autoplay={{ delay: 5000, disableOnInteraction: false }}
      >
        {movies.map((movie, i) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={i}>
            <img src={`${poster_url}${movie.poster_path}`} alt="" />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
};

export default CardSlider;
```

App.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Header from './components/header/header.jsx';
import useStore from './store/store.js';
import CardSlider from './components/cards-slider/card-slider.jsx';

const App = () => {
  const { movies, fetchMovies } = useStore();
  const backgroundRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();

    const handleSlideChange = (swiper) => {
      const activeSlide = swiper.activeIndex;
      // Implement logic to update background based on active slide using backgroundRef
      console.log('Active slide index:', activeSlide);
    };

    const swiper = backgroundRef.current; // Assuming reference points to Swiper instance
    if (swiper) {
      swiper.on('slideChange', handleSlideChange);
    }

    return () => {
      if (swiper) {
        swiper.off('slideChange', handleSlideChange);
      }
    };
  }, [fetchMovies]);

  console.log(movies);

  return (
    <div ref={backgroundRef}>
      <Header />
      <CardSlider movies={movies} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

store.js:

```
import { create } from 'zustand';
import axios from 'axios';
import { api_key, url } from '../api/config.js';

const useStore = create((set) => ({
  movies: [],
  fetchMovies: async () => {
    const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${url}discover/movie?page=1&api_key=${api_key}&language=ru-RU`);
    set({ movies: results });
  },
}));

export default useStore;
```